# Error when create MAVEN project using command line

Tags: maven, command-line

Used the steps mentioned [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)

Command line used:

```bash
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.4 -DinteractiveMode=false
```

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate
>   (default-cli) on project exerciseone: Execution default-cli of goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate failed:
>   A required class was missing while executing
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate:
>   org/apache/commons/collections/ExtendedProperties

Answer (score 0):

with interactiveMode=false, you must specified the archetype's artifactId and groupId
eg.

```
mvn archetype:generate  -DinteractiveMode=false -DarchetypeGroupId=org.example -DarchetypeArtifactId=project-archetype-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.0-SNAPSHOT  -DartifactId=example-project -DgroupId=abc.def.ghk -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dcustom-property=192.168.20.101
```